# rails favicon icon works in Firefox but not Chrome?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink, favicon

Rails Code (HAML):

```
= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico'
```

The `favicon.ico` is located at

```
app/assets/images/favicon.ico
```

It works locally and remotely (in production) in Firefox but for both local and remote Chrome shows no image

Viewing production source in either browser shows:

```
<readyhead>
...

<link href="/assets/favicon-2d05a112081aa8cc9c3caa576862077d.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
...
</readyhead>
```

Viewing development source in either browser shows:

```
<readyhead>
...
<link href="/assets/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
...
</readyhead>
```

I don't have IE but you can see it at http://www.railslinks.com (I'm curious to know!)

Comment: What kind of nonsense is `<readyhead>`? Replace it with `<head>` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect your page source with chrome dev tools you can see how Chrome parses your HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <readyhead>
      <!-- some more stuff ... -->

      <link href="/assets/favicon-2d05a112081aa8cc9c3caa576862077d.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
    </readyhead>

    <!-- some more stuff ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that `<readyhead>` is not a valid HTML element, so Chrome creates a separate `<head>` element as replacement and assumes that `<readyhead>` belongs inside the `<body>` tag.

To fix this, you must rename `<readyhead>` to `<head>` and then Chrome should parse your HTML correctly. What is this element supposed to be anyway? It's not valid HTML.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221263/what-is-rails-readyhead-instead-of-head) seems to be related.